# Hadoop: How can I set it to use more processes

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am running MR program on a quad-core machine with hyper-threading, and Hadoop 1.2.1 is run in pseudo-distributed mode on that machine.

## What I did

I have a 1GB file, and ran the program multiple times with different settings for map tasks and slots (no reduce), and here's the result I've got:

```
  split     mapred.tasktracker.    No. of
  size      map.tasks.maximum      process   time   
--------------------------------------------------------
  iGB       1                      1         04m 13s
  1GB       2                      1         04m 10s
  1GB       4                      1         04m 12s

  500MB     1                      2         02m 14s
  500MB     2                      2         02m 13s
  500MB     4                      2         02m 13s

  250MB     1                      2         02m 17s
  250MB     2                      2         02m 16s
  250MB     4                      2         02m 18s
  250MB     8                      2         02m 16s

  125MB     1                      2         02m 25s
  125MB     2                      2         02m 23s
  125MB     4                      2         02m 24s
  125MB     8                      2         02m 24s
```

## Question

The result made sense to me when the split size is set to 1GB and 500MB. But, I expected to get up to 4 java processes in the TOP screen when the split size = 250MB and the slot size is greater or equal to 4. Or, when split size = 125MB and the slot size is greater or equal to 4.
(I see a few more java processes but they are sleeping and using 0.1 %CPU)

The MR programs are written in Python, so I'm using Hadoop Streaming, and I do see 1~2 Python processes at each run. Does it mean that 2 python processes and 2 java processes occupied all available cores? But the machine is quad-core with hyper threading, so doesn't that mean that I could have up to 8 processes running at the same time?
Is this the memory issue?? CPU usage is low. Or am I missing something here?

I've tried adding this, and still can't see more than 2 processes running at the same time..

```
  <property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx512m</value>
  </property>
```

## Edit

When I use `mapreduce` instead of `mapred` in the property, I get more info while running but it slows down because of printing the log. 
The INFO shows something like this:

```
mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
streaming.PipeMapRed: PipeMapRed exec [/Users/hadoop/./map.py]
...
streaming.StreamJob: map 0% reduce 0%
mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0

etc...
```

## Edit

Another thing is that when I add more reduce tasks, I do see more java processes in the TOP screen. It's just not adding more MAP processes...

Comment: Note that this property has different names (in fact, prefix, `mapred` or `mapreduce`) for different hadoop versions: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html.

Comment: The latter settings, `mapred.child.java.opts` deal with memory allocation and prevent runtime memory error, you'll see them in logs if any.

Comment: Can you update with your new info? And you hadoop version.

Comment: @alko I added the new INFO I got in my question. My hadoop version is 1.2.1. Is there any info that I should be looking for?

Comment: What is your value for `mapred.map.tasks`?

Comment: @AlfonsoNishikawa After finding out that it will only suggest the number of map tasks to the framework, I kind of forgot about it and did not set it to anything. Should I?

Comment: I suggest give it a shot :) Configure it to 4, for example. Who knows...